PyABSA for Aspect Based Sentiment ANalysis
I am working on Aspect based Sentiment Analysis and came across this nice package - PyABSA.
I've found that version 2 is problematic with the models not getting loaded, so I'm using version 1.
There is a slight problem being that it works with downloading the checkpoints from Google Drive. This means that after a number of calls, Google blocks the IP Address from making calls. There is the option to download the checkpoint and use it manually.
I'm not sure how to go about this, or how to call it when manually downloaded, and there isn't much documentation. Just wondering if anyone here has used it and downloaded the checkpoints?
Here is a sample of the usage on the page, showing how the checkpoints are used when downloaded from online directly.
from pyabsa.functional import ATEPCCheckpointManager #actual line of code


examples = ['But the staff was so nice to us .',
            'But the staff was so horrible to us .',
            r'Not only was the food outstanding , but the little ` perks \' were great .',
            'It took half an hour to get our check , which was perfect since we could sit , have drinks and talk !',
            'It was pleasantly uncrowded , the service was delightful , the garden adorable , '
            'the food -LRB- from appetizers to entrees -RRB- was delectable .',
            'How pretentious and inappropriate for MJ Grill to claim that it provides power lunch and dinners !'
            ]

inference_source = ABSADatasetList.Restaurant14
aspect_extractor = ATEPCCheckpointManager.get_aspect_extractor(checkpoint='english')
atepc_result = aspect_extractor.extract_aspect(inference_source=inference_source,
                                               save_result=True,
                                               print_result=True,  # print the result
                                               pred_sentiment=True,  # Predict the sentiment of extracted aspect terms
                                               )


Just providing an update that this is done automatically by the model. The problem I had seems to be from not being able to create a virtual environment which allows the model to run as it should, on Databricks.
Running the model on my local Jupyter notebooks allows the checkpoints to be automatically downloaded.
